# Hide button in Navbar on when different component loads in VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to hide a button in my Navbar in vue.js, so you should see the button in one component and not the other. I am using bootstrap for the UI and vue.js for the app. So far I have done this in the header component:

**Header component**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" v-if="modal">
  Added playlist <span class="badge badge-light">{{List.length}}</span>
</button>

<script>
data: function() {
    return {
      modal: true
    };
  },
</script>
```

Then in the component that hides the button, I have done the following:

```
<script>
data: function() {
    return {
      modal: false
    };
  },
</script>
```

But this does not work? Any ideas how this can be done in VUE JS, I am in the learning phase for Vue.

Comment: please mention the structure of your components

Comment: Well you can use multiple components to make different nav's and move in and out using router or if statements, you can use an if statement on the button itself to see if a certain state has changed. It's just about how you want to handle it.